# Best way to queue scores offline to be submitted later to Game Center?

Tags: objective-c, ios, security, gamekit

Specifically, I am wondering whether I should create a GKScore or save the score value in my own object. Either way, I'd save the score object to file as a .plist in case the app is terminated before the score can be successfully submitted to the game Center servers.

Perhaps there is an advantage to saving it as a GKScore because the date might be preserved, but more importantly, is a GKScore more tamper-resistant?  I'm looking to head off cheaters who have access to modifying the saved file direcly, thus modifying their score before it gets submitted to game center.

UPDATE: after reading the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13) a bit more closely, it tells us that in iOS 4, re-reporting scores is left up to your app; however, in iOS 5 this is automatically handled by a reporting task in the background.  Therefore, this question is only really relevant for iOS 4 (which I and most others still plan to fully support, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little late to this discussion, however....

This topic is briefly discussed in the Game Center Essentials talk by Allan Schaffer, Apple Game Technologies Evangelist.  This was released to iTunes U in 2011.

At around the 22:30 mark, the discussion turns to archiving the GKScore object for later submission.  To limit cheating, the recommendations are to:

- Add a checksum to the file
- Add a hash to the score
- Limit Score Submissions to known "Valid" amounts

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make this feature secure because this is an implicit violation of [CWE-602](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html).   It doesn't matter if the value is being stored on the flash memory or in random access memory,  at the end of the day the user has more control over the device than you do.   As a developer you are a guest and you should play nice.  Perhaps you are looking for "(in)[security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)".

Comment: Thanks for the information, but in my question, I've assumed that queuing scores provides a window to manipulate scores.  My question is: is encoding the score as a GKScore more tamper-_resistant_?  I'm haven't ever looked at data encoded into an NSData object and then saved to a .plist so I have no reference to go by.

Comment: @Jonathan Sibley  i don't think that encoding or other methods of obscuring the data helps in the slightest.

Comment: It is my responsibility as a game developer to my customers to try to uphold the integrity of things like the high scores list.  This includes making a reasonable effort to make an archived GKScore tamper-resistant, as long as it is transparent to the customers who are not trying to tamper.You seem to have taken my use of the word "secure" to mean 100% not tamper-able by anyone on earth.  It goes without saying that such a level of security would be impossible to achieve.